# Conditional formatting google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to use a custom formula to highlight a row based on the value of the "Q" column in the row. if the q column contains 'TRASH',  I want to colour the row red. In my case , as you can see in the screenshot and based on what I'm getting from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/WvUSJXrTWUY my custom formula is in the screenshot.

```
=$Q$8:$Q$8= "TRASH"
```

The formatting is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings in conditional formatting will change the background color of a row, from cell A to R, in your file It starts at row 1 and goes to the last row in the sheet:

- Apply to range:  A1:R
- Format cells if...: Custom formula is
- (formula:) =$Q1="TRASH"

Set the Formatting style as you wish to highlight the row.  The $ holds the formula to column Q but no $ in front of the number allows it to increment.

Note that the Range will change to include the last row in your sheet.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! When using conditional formulas should they be calculated referencing the first row?

Comment: You could start at any row, change both instances of 1 to the row where you wish to start.  So if you wish to start in row 8, the range becomes A8:R and the formula is =$Q8="TRASH"