# Mark every cell that includes a country name

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, gs-vlookup, google-sheets-formula

I need to mark every cell in column A that includes a country name. I have almost a 60k long range.

I have tried VLOOKUP but I cannot use my range as a search parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional formatting google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941836/conditional-formatting-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Please adjust your choice of countries/names in the formula below to suit then select ColumnA and: Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... Custom formula is and:

```
 =regexmatch(A1,"Albania|Algeria|Andorra|Angola|Antigua and Barbuda|Argentina|Armenia|Australia|Austria|Azerbaijan|The Bahamas|Bahrain|Bangladesh|Barbados|Belarus|Belgium|Belize|Benin|Bhutan|Bolivia|Bosnia and Herzegovina|Botswana|Brazil|Brunei|Bulgaria|Burkina Faso|Burundi|Cabo Verde|Cambodia|Cameroon|Canada|Central African Republic|Chad|Chile|China|Colombia|Comoros|Democratic Republic of the Congo|Republic of the Congo|Costa Rica|Côte d’Ivoire|Croatia|Cuba|Cyprus|Czech Republic|Denmark|Djibouti|Dominica|Dominican Republic|East Timor|Ecuador|Egypt|El Salvador|Equatorial Guinea|Eritrea|Estonia|Ethiopia|Fiji|Finland|France|Gabon|The Gambia|Georgia|Germany|Ghana|Greece|Grenada|Guatemala|Guinea|Guinea-Bissau|Guyana|Haiti|Honduras|Hungary|Iceland|India|Indonesia|Iran|Iraq|Ireland|Israel|Italy|Jamaica|Japan|Jordan|Kazakhstan|Kenya|Kiribati|North Korea|South Korea|Kosovo|Kuwait|Kyrgyzstan|Laos|Latvia|Lebanon|Lesotho|Liberia|Libya|Liechtenstein|Lithuania|Luxembourg|Macedonia|Madagascar|Malawi|Malaysia|Maldives|Mali|Malta|Marshall Islands|Mauritania|Mauritius|Mexico|Federated States of Micronesia|Moldova|Monaco|Mongolia|Montenegro|Morocco|Mozambique|Myanmar|Namibia|Nauru|Nepal|Netherlands|New Zealand|Nicaragua|Niger|Nigeria|Norway|Oman|Pakistan|Palau|Panama|Papua New Guinea|Paraguay|Peru|Philippines|Poland|Portugal|Qatar|Romania|Russia|Rwanda|Saint Kitts and Nevis|Saint Lucia|Saint Vincent and the Grenadines|Samoa|San Marino|Sao Tome and Principe|Saudi Arabia|Senegal|Serbia|Seychelles|Sierra Leone|Singapore|Slovakia|Slovenia|Solomon Islands|Somalia|South Africa|Spain|Sri Lanka|South Sudan|Sudan|Suriname|Swaziland|Sweden|Switzerland|Syria|Taiwan|Tajikistan|Tanzania|Thailand|Togo|Tonga|Trinidad and Tobago|Tunisia|Turkey|Turkmenistan|Tuvalu|Uganda|Ukraine|United Arab Emirates|United Kingdom|United States|Uruguay|Uzbekistan|Vanuatu|Vatican City|Venezuela|Vietnam|Yemen|Zambia|Zimbabwe")
```

with Formatting style of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Be prepared for a long wait - several cups of tea, not merely one.

You might be prepared to abbreviate Congo, Korea, Sudan etc.